# Why are major 500 error codes deprecated in symfony?

Tags: symfony, httpresponse

I don't get why major error codes like 500 and 504 are tagged as deprecated in symfony. Is there a reason for that?

[image]

Comment: What FQCN are you refer? Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response is not declared as @deprecated  .... check https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php

Comment: It is kind of strange. In 4.4.0 they are marked as depreciated but 5.0.0 just has them as regular codes.  Might be a question for the Symfony Slack channel.

Comment: I was referring to the 4.4.x version - since I am currently studying for the symfony 4 cert.

Comment: Okay.  The depreciate annotation only applies to the single const immediately following it.  Notice how HTTP_RESERVED_FOR_WEBDAV_ADVANCED_COLLECTIONS_EXPIRED_PROPOSAL and HTTP_TOO_EARLY have the same value.  So the WEBDAV one has gone away in 5.0.  I'm sure the associated RFC has more information.

Comment: @Cerad ah - sure. Makes total sence - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case people are not reading comments, this is the important bit:

> The depreciate annotation only applies to the single const immediately following it.

So on that list, it only applies to HTTP 425.